# typescript generics limit number | string

Tags: typescript

I want to code a react input component that receives a `defaultValue` parameter type of `string | number`. This component has a state type means the `defaultValue` type;

This my code:

```
type TypeName<T> = T extends number ? "number" : "string";

interface IInputProps<P extends string | number>{
    defaultValue: P,
    rule: (value: P)=>boolean,
    onChange: (value: P)=>void
}

interface IInputState<P extends string | number>{
    value: P,
    type: TypeName<P>
}

class Input<P extends string | number> extends Component<IInputProps<P>,IInputState<P>>{
    constructor(props:IInputProps<P>){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            type: typeof props.defaultValue,
            value: this.props.defaultValue
        }
```

In the constructor has error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Input/index.tsx:21:4
    TS2322: Type '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' is not assignable to type 'TypeName<P>'.
  Type '"string"' is not assignable to type 'TypeName<P>'.
```

What can I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you are more clever than the compiler.  While *you* understand that whatever `P` is, the value `typeof props.defaultValue` will be of type `TypeName<P>`, the compiler can't figure it out.  It only realizes that `typeof props.defaultValue` can be one of the string values that come out of the `typeof` operator: `"string"` or `"number"` or `"boolean"`, etc.  And even if it realized that it must only be `"string"` or `"number"`, it's not clever enough to realize that the value is correlated to `P` in the right way to make it `TypeName<P>` (at least as of TypeScript 3.2).

The most straightforward way to deal with this is just to accept that you are smarter than the compiler, and to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that `typeof props.defaultValue` can be treated `as` a value of type `TypeName<P>`.  The following should compile:

```
this.state = {
    type: typeof props.defaultValue as TypeName<P>, // assertion
    value: this.props.defaultValue
}
```

I don't think there's currently any way to lead the compiler through the steps so that it can verify `TypeName<P>` itself, so anything you do (like making a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)) will be equivalent to an assertion.

If you find yourself needing to do this assertion often, you can abstract it into a function:

```
function getTypeName<T extends string | number>(t: T): TypeName<T> {
  return typeof t as TypeName<T>; // assertion
}
```

which will at least confine the assertion to a single place and hide the issue from subsequent users of `getTypeName()`:

```
this.state = {
    type: getTypeName(props.defaultValue), // no assertion here
    value: this.props.defaultValue
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your patience.
Maybe it hard to avoid to use ```as```.